# SQL Server 2005 - install & setup -ADD_LOCAL property / template.ini / UPGRADE property

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition on my Windows 7 Ultimate laptop.

When the installation runs, I am getting the following error :-

A component that you have specified in the ADD_LOCAL property is already installed. To upgrade the existing component, refer to the template.ini and set the UPGRADE property to the name of the component.

I had installed an Express version from the Web Platform installer, but I'm sure I removed that. Also installed were compact editions from a mobile development workshop I did last year. I removed those also.

Currently my Uninstall or change a program list in Control Panel has the following SQL Server related entries :-

- Microsoft SQL Server 2005
- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility
- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Books Online (English)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Mobile [ENU] Developer Tools
- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Upgrade Advisor (English)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
- Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
- Microsoft SQL Server Setup Support Files (English)
- Microsoft SQL Server VSS Writer

Where do I go from here to get this product installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I followed this article.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/50164862-ef20-4758-9c7a-0d6ae8f1b3f9/

After rebooting and running the installation again, and choosing just the client components (the problem part of the install) it is now installing smoothly.

I'm going to rerun the installation in a few moments and install the SQL Engine, Reporting Services, Analysis Services, and the other options such as the sample databases.

Job done; it seems.